# OWIN - Associating application information to auth server

Tags: authentication, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I've been following the tutorial found here for setting up an authorization server, separate from my client app. http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/
I can get his example up and working, but I feel like I'm missing a few steps for my application.

I'd like to have this authorization server provide oauth tokens, which will be used by a separate project (and potentially multiple others) to authenticate users. I understand the point of this is to separate authorization logic and business logic, but I'm not sure how to actually pair created users on the auth server to users on the application.

For example, when a user creates an account for the first time, they'll send their username/password to the authorization server. At what point does the app also create its own user information (empty profile and settings etc), and how do I then store the application's userID with the authorization information? I've tried adding the client UserID as a claim on the auth server, but I'm not sure if I fully understand what that means or if that's the correct approach.

Basically, what I think I should be able to do, but not sure how to do it, is in my ASP.Net WebApi application, it should accept an Authorization: Bearer < token > header, and somehow be able to grab the UserID (relevant to that specific application) from the authorization server. A second, unrelated application should be able to accept the same access token and get its own UserID (assuming the user has an account with both applications) from the auth server.

Am I looking at this the right way? How do I associate different applications' UserIDs with the users created on the auth server?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, if you're using Microsoft's OAuth Owin implementation, you should just be able to override OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and then override the appropriate Grant*().

See http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server for more details.

If you're just using ResourceOwner grant, it's fairly straight forward:

```
public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{

    var user = ...;
    if (!PasswordProvider.ValidatePassword(context.Password, user.Password))
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The password is incorrect.");
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    // Build Claims Identity
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OwinAuthConfig.OAuthAuthorizationOptions.AuthenticationType);
    identity.BuildClaims(user);

    // Create the Properties
    var properties = CreateProperties(user);

    // Create the ticket and process it.
    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Where build claims is something like:

```
public static class ApplicationOAuthProviderHelper
{
    public static void BuildClaims(this ClaimsIdentity identity, User user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString())
        };

        // Get custom claims, like user app ids.
        // ex. Claim { ClaimType = "app1/UserId", Value = "34242" }
        var externalAppClaims = MagicalFunctionThatGetsExternalClaims(user);
        foreach(var claim in externalAppClaims)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(claim.ClaimType, claim.Value));
        }

        identity.AddClaims(claims);
    }
}
```

Which then might be used in a Web API controller as:

```
var userIdString = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("app1/UserId");
```

Let me know if that doesn't answer you question!